# Why does sizeof(int) vary across different operating systems?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

I wounder why size of int depends on which OS one is using ,in C & C++. It's ok if size of pointer varies, but why size of integer. If 16 bit OS sizeof(int) = 2 byte, for 32 bit sizeof(int) = 4 byte. Why so?

Thanks.

Comment: Different platforms prefer different alignments and implement different op sets.

Comment: That is OK.. but why it come down to only integer

Comment: IMHO integer size etc has more relation with the underlying processor data bus size than with the OS.

Comment: @NeonGlow: On same pc if you install different os, you will get different size

Comment: @PranitPKothari, not only integral types may vary. The witdth of a `double` may vary as well.

Comment: @PranitPKothari : Different OSes cant have same ABI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171177/what-is-application-binary-interface-abi].

Comment: @NeonGlow Sure they can. e.g. some of the BSDs implements a linux ABI.   ReactOS implements the windows ABI.

Comment: @all: why is this question downvoted so much? It's a valid question about the implementation details of compiled languages.

Comment: @Andreas - If you read it fast, it sure looks like *"Why do rich people have all the money?"*. The size of an integer is part of what defines the "bitness".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the sizes of data types change as the Operating System changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673735/why-do-the-sizes-of-data-types-change-as-the-operating-system-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ standard

1.7.1 states:

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A
>   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set ...

then 3.9.1.1 states:

> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store
>   any member of the implementation’s basic character set.

So we can infer that `char` is actually a byte. Most importantly 3.9.1.2 also says:

> There are ﬁve signed integer types: “signed char”, “short int”, “int”,
>   “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type provides at
>   least as much storage as those preceding it in the list. Plain ints
>   have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution
>   environment; the other signed integer types are provided to meet
>   special needs.

So in other words the size of `int` is (a) guaranteed to be at least a byte and (b) naturally aligned to the OS/hardware it's running on so most likely these days to be 64 bit or (for many older systems) 32 bit.

Comment: Or for [some even older systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about/6972551#6972551) it can even be 36-bits.

Comment: @Bo hmmm systems on which multics run.. for instance :-)

Answer (score 7):

> Why so?

Historical reasons.

Before the advent of the ANSI C standard and `size_t` in 1989, `int` was the type used to index into arrays. `malloc` took an `int` as its argument, `strlen` returned one. Thus `int` had to be large enough to index any array, but small enough to not cause too much overhead. For file offsets, typically a larger type such as `long` was `typedef`'d to `off_t`.

On the [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) were C was first implemented in the early 1970s, `int` was as large as a processor register: 16 bits. On larger machines such as the [VAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX), it was widened to 32 bits to allow for larger arrays.

This convention has been largely abandoned; the C and C++ standards use `size_t` and `ssize_t` for indices and lenghts of arrays. On 64-bit platforms, often `int` is still 32 bits wide while `size_t` is 64 bits. (Many older APIs, e.g. [CBLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/), still use `int` for indices, though.)

Answer (score 2):

A *byte* is the smallest unit of memory which your target system can handle and uniquely address. As such, the size of a byte is platform and compiler-dependant, but in most settings is 8 bits.

So, assuming a byte is 8 bits, this would mean that 64 bits equals 8 bytes, 32 bits equals 4 bytes and 16 bits equals 2 bytes.

On a fuzzy level, an "X bit system" is a system where basic values (registers, ints, etc.) are X bits by default. Thus, how many bits your system natively uses immediately affects how many bytes are needed to hold those values.

Comment: Size of byte is compiler-dependent?

Comment: @PranitPKothari It depends on your target platform, but is guaranteed to be "at least 8 bits". This is because some special hardware has properties which make other byte sizes more suitable. For example, if your hardware addresses has a 16-bit resolution, you need a byte to be at least 16 bits.

 See my edit regarding what a byte really is.

Comment: It doesn't have to be at least 8 bits

Comment: @a3f In standard C and C++, yes it does.

Comment: According to the C++ standard, section 1.7.1: *"A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementationdefined."* Given that it has to be large enough to contain any 8-bit character, it does have to be at least 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be reformulated as why the different types of data structure depends on the CPU. This can be justified simply by the fact that C is a language that can be used in low-level programming. You can see in [Data Types in the Kernel](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf) how that data types are defined for different types of CPU in Linux. This is link to word length of the processor.