# Why do datatypes have different sizes on different architectures? (i.e. a C int on 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit)

Tags: c, types, cpu-architecture

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes) that it depends on the specific compiler so you always have to use sizeof() to find out the size, however when reading about datatype sizes i always read things such as "on a typical 64-bit machine datatype_x is x_bytes long" "on a 16-bit machine..."

Why is it like this?
What's the correlation between datatype size and the machine architecture?

**Edit:** The reason why i posted this question despite there being similar duplicates is because im not content with the answer "It depends on the compiler, and the compiler is usually made to achieve the best performance on the system". I wanted to know why certain size for the datatype on the given bit system is considered to give the best performance. Which I guess has to do with how instructions are processed by the cpu but I didn't want to go and read a bunch about CPUs and such, just want to know the part that's relevant to this question.

Comment: Umm, it's the *Hardware API*... e.g. ARM is different from x86, is different from x86_64, etc.. The physical processor register sizes are different, and compilers are there to translate code into machine language to run on that hardware.

Comment: The `int` type used to be the "natural" word-size (or rather *register* word size) for the architecture. So on a 16-bit system it is 16 bits wide, on a 32-bit system it is 32 bits wide.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there an advantage to using a complete word instead of the minimum required by standard?

Comment: @jose The advantage of using a complete `int` vs. `short` and `char` is that code _tends_ to be faster and take up less code space.

Comment: so many duplicates: [Does the size of the integer or any other data types in C dependent on the underlying architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11380709/995714), [integer size in c depends on what?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5256000/995714), [Why do the sizes of data types change as the Operating System changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12673735/995714), [Why does the size of an int vary in some compilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22893712/995714), [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/995714)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sizeof(int) vary across different operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256695/why-does-sizeofint-vary-across-different-operating-systems)

Comment: forcing an int to be 32 bits on an 8/16/18/36/...-bit architecture would be a pain in performance. [There are a lot of systems like that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6971886/995714)

Answer (score 1):

> "What's the correlation between datatype size and the machine architecture?"

There is no defined correlation.  There is a *tendency* or [more like guidelines than actual rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6kgS_AwuH0) that `int` corresponds to the processor's integer width and is at least 16 bits.  Minimum "limit of size_t ... 65535" C11 §7.20.3 1

> Why is it like this?

That is the strength of C.  `size_t` follows the processors "best/native" size making for good performance, tightness of executable code and the platforms memory capacity.  Yet there are exceptions to the guideline.

It is also a weakness of C in that it varies from platform to platform.

Use fixed width types like `int32_t` if code goals requires it.

Comment: So if I understand what you are saying is "*Stick to the code...*"

Comment: thank you, so can we say that the reason why compilers make int bigger on bigger higher bit systems is because it adds extra range to the datatype while having no effect on speed? I would assume that the increased range on the int comes at the cost of some speed, but this is because I'm not sure how the instructions are processed by the system, mind clearing that one out for me

Comment: @jose It is the overall computation rate that is important.  An 8-bit processor is easier to construct that a 64-bit one, but is it 8 times faster?  OTOH, a 1024-bit processor may be too unwieldy to construct and route the circuit.  Faster/best depends on the types of problems the  current market requires.  With memory needs exceeding 4 GB, addressing beyond 32-bit is favored.  The details involve any considerations, worthy of a thesis paper.